# Tensorflow: create a tensor A, such that A[i][i - 1] = A[i - 1][j] = 1

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have to create a 2-dimensional tensor A in tensorflow, such that A[i][i - 1] = A[i - 1][j] = 1 and other elements are equal to zero.

This tensor should have shape equal to another tensor's shape, that's why I can't create it using numpy array.

Could you help me, please?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to create a matrix (2-dim tensor) with two "lines" of 1, above and below the diagonal?

Comment: @sygi Yes, you're right.

Answer (score 0):

```
size = 100
indices = []
for i in xrange(size-1):
  indices.append([i, i+1])
  indices.append([i+1, i])

dense = tf.sparse_to_dense(indices, [size, size], [1]*2*(size-1))
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(dense)
```

Comment: The problem is that size is not int, but another tensor`s shape, that's why I can't use loops and numpy.

Comment: Ah, I don't know (and am not sure if it is possible) how to do it, then.

Comment: Thanks a lot anyway!

Comment: It's better to [add more context/explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) around code (as opposed to just having a code-only answer) as that makes the answer more useful.